# Deleting more than one picture - running out of memory

Tags: excel, image, vba, memory

I am trying to delete 4 pictures in my sheet, they all follow a certain nomenclature:

```
Sub ABilderLoeschen(OfferteAuftrag As String)
On Error GoTo exitPicLoop1
With ActiveSheet.Pictures
    .ShapeRange("Offerte_1").Delete
    .ShapeRange("Offerte_2").Delete
    .ShapeRange("Offerte_3").Delete
    .ShapeRange("Offerte_4").Delete
    .ShapeRange("Offerte_5").Delete
    .ShapeRange("Offerte_6").Delete
    .ShapeRange("Offerte_7").Delete
    .ShapeRange("Offerte_8").Delete
    .ShapeRange("Offerte_9").Delete
    .ShapeRange("Offerte_10").Delete
exitPicLoop1:
    On Error GoTo exitPicLoop2
    .ShapeRange("Auftrag_1").Delete
    .ShapeRange("Auftrag_2").Delete
    .ShapeRange("Auftrag_3").Delete
    .ShapeRange("Auftrag_4").Delete
    .ShapeRange("Auftrag_5").Delete
    .ShapeRange("Auftrag_6").Delete
    .ShapeRange("Auftrag_7").Delete
    .ShapeRange("Auftrag_8").Delete
    .ShapeRange("Auftrag_9").Delete
    .ShapeRange("Auftrag_10").Delete
End With
exitPicLoop2:

On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

This is a sample script, I am running a loop in my real function but both throw the same error: `Runtime Error 7 : Out of Memory`

It always happens after I delete the first picture. Earlier I deleted the first two pictures by calling the function again and it worked.

Is there a way to get rid of the error?

Comment: are you using excel-2013?

Comment: Did you run that code and does it behave exactly as your "real" code?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
Sub ABilderLoeschen(OfferteAuftrag As String)
For Each pt in ActiveSheet.Pictures
    If Left(pt.Name, 8) = "Offerte_" or Left(pt.Name, 8) = "Auftrag_" Then
        pt.delete
    End If
Next
End Sub
```